# How to set the cursor in a specific location in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, ckeditor

Can I possibly set the cursor at a specific location in CKEditor? Probably, it would be based on index or text searching etc? Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure but I think you want to use [selectRanges](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dom.selection.html#selectRanges) I found in javascript API

Comment: . Thanks for your reply again ... In fact, I am just wondering whether I could set the cursor location based on the index or some text string? ...